# Getting Spring RestTemplate request timeout but connectionTimeout and ReadTimeout not set

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using spring RestTemplate to make HTTP requests from my service as follows

```
public ResponseEntity<String> request(String url, HttpMethod method, String body,
                                      Map<String, String> authHeaders) throws HttpHelperException {

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = getHttpHeader(authHeaders);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(body, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, entity, String.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
        Map<String, String> map = null;
        try {
            map = new HashMap<>(objectMapper.readValue(new String(e.getResponseBodyAsString()), Map.class));
            throw new HttpHelperException(AppStatus.valueOf(e.getStatusCode().value()),
                    map.get("message"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw e;
        }

    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new HttpHelperException(e);
    }
    
    return response;
}
```

where RestTemplate bean is defined as

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.build();
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(customResponseErrorHandler);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Since the last few days, I have started seeing read timeout exception

```
HttpHelperException: I/O error on POST request for <request_url>: Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I am facing this for multiple services and the errors all started around the same time - which leads me to conclude that the issue must be in my service itself (Also, other services which access the same endpoint are not facing this issue).

I am not setting any value to connectionTimeout and readTimeout - in which case the timeout should be infinite. What could be causing the issue?

Comment: Hi Pravesh, any luck with the problem? Looks like I have the same issue. Cheers

Comment: Hi @Dmytro, no luck with the spring issue. In my case the issue actually turned out to be with the service I was calling and we were able to fix that. However I still did not understand how the default timeout with spring works